# Winform image toggle button

Tags: c#, winforms

Well after a long search on web and downloading few projects I landed here for an overall easy to use and small code to implement a toggle button on c# winform project.

I want to have my button to be toggled i.e. two different image possibly with two different text, even I can make the images to have text on it.

Any quick suggestion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The usual way is to use a `CheckBox` with `Appearance=Button`.

You can toggle its `ImageIndex` and `Text`  in the `CheckedChanged` event.

You need to associate it with a well-prepared `ImageList` of the right `ImageSize` an `ColorDepth`.

You can get away with ca 3 lines of code:

```
private void checkBox1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (checkBox1.Checked)
      { checkBox1.ImageIndex = 1; checkBox1.Text = "Sue"; }
    else
      { checkBox1.ImageIndex = 2; checkBox1.Text = "Ellen"; }
}
```

Comment: Let me try with a customized size

Comment: Using an Imagelist you can have a size of up to 256x256. If you need larger Buttons you will need to store the Images somewhere else..